# Understanding commit failure from the consumer when leader has changed

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Consider following real obfuscated logs:

```
 19:33:48,409 99733391 (pool-6-thread-11) ERROR [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [] [Consumer clientId=app2.maria1.mcdonalnds_service_msg, groupId=mcdonalnds_service_msg] Offset commit failed on partition service_megaman_mt-mcdonalnds_service_msg-1 at offset 75796: This is not the correct coordinator.
 19:33:48,410 99733392 (pool-6-thread-11) INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [] [Consumer clientId=app2.maria1.mcdonalnds_service_msg, groupId=mcdonalnds_service_msg] Group coordinator kafka1.maria4.internal:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
 19:33:48,414 99733396 (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) WARN  [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender] [] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 16386 on topic-partition service_megaman_mo-mcdonalnds_service_msg-1, retrying (99 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION
 19:33:48,510 99733492 (pool-6-thread-11) INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [] [Consumer clientId=app2.maria1.mcdonalnds_service_msg, groupId=mcdonalnds_service_msg] Discovered group coordinator kafka3.maria4.internal:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
 19:33:48,528 99733510 (pool-6-thread-11) ERROR [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [] [Consumer clientId=app2.maria1.mcdonalnds_service_msg, groupId=mcdonalnds_service_msg] Offset commit failed on partition service_megaman_mt-mcdonalnds_service_msg-1 at offset 75796: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
 19:33:48,528 99733510 (pool-6-thread-11) ERROR [com.bob.kafka.consumer.ListenableKafkaConsumer] [] Aborting consumer [mcdonalnds_service_msg] for topics [[service_megaman_mt-mcdonalnds_service_msg]] operation due to failure! Cause: 
 org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

As far as I understand the exception message about poll() is not really the cause. So what happened:
 1. Coordinator was not available
 2. Consumer found new coordinator
 3. New coordinator did not recognise offset so rejected the commit

What I am trying to figure out is the options to recover from this situation. This is not intermittent issue but happened once in a year so the setting on poll would not have helped if leader died.

**What happens now:** Original application code was simply closing consumers which is wrong , caused alerts and woke up just about everyone as application stopped consuming messages :-)

**What I want to happen:**
Consumer is restarted, doesn't die if loses connection to coordinator

**What I am not sure about:**

1. Why coordinator is not aware of this member
2. If I understand the issue correctly. :-)
3. On service side with Java Kafka lib for KafkaConsumer class I
       should call **close** and **subscribe** or **unsubscribe** and
       **subscribe** to fullfill my consumer recovery scenario.
4. What is going to happen to the processed
   offset
       which was rejected by new coordinator? Since offset was not commited I assume consumer will re-read the same messages?

Following [post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/638#issuecomment-384416711) for Spring-kafka looks very similar issue but the service does not use Spring so this is of limited use to me.

Comment: this may happen when your consumer take more than the set timeout before committing issuing a rebalance. You can try to change the number of records fetched and the timeouts. Also as suggested by Deadpool add a listener to save the offset in that case and restart from it